# Wordpress WP_Query, exclude date from meta term

Tags: wordpress

I'm making an API using WP-JSON for a client, they're using a plugin that manage events and the API should return next events, not the past.

```
function app_get_newer_posts($data) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 99,
        'paged' => $data['page'],
        'meta_key'   => 'ovaem_date_start_time',
        'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'asc'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        $ret = [];

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $term = get_term(get_the_ID,'');
            $query->the_post();
            setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT.UTF8', 'it.UTF8', 'it_IT.UTF-8', 'it.UTF-8');
            if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ovaem_date_start_time')[0] < date("Y-m-d")) {
                $ret['schedule'][] = [
                    'date' => strftime('%e %B %Y',get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ovaem_date_start_time')[0]),
                    'category' => [ get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'categorie' )[0]->name ],
                    'premium' => false,
                    'url' => get_the_permalink(),
                    'groups' => [[
                        'time' => utf8_encode( strftime("%d %b %Y", get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ovaem_date_start_time')[0]) ),
                        'sessions' => [[
                            'id' => get_the_ID(),
                            'name' => html_entity_decode(the_title('','',false), ENT_QUOTES),
                            'location' => get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'location')[0]->name,
                            'description' => get_the_content(),
                            'timeStart' => date('d M Y h:i',get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ovaem_date_start_time')[0]),
                            'timeEnd' => date('d M Y h:i',get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ovaem_date_end_time')[0]),
                            'categories' => [ get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'categorie' )[0]->name ],
                            'pic' => get_the_post_thumbnail_url(),
                            'position' => [
                                'lat' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ovaem_event_map_lat')[0], 
                                'lng' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ovaem_event_map_lng')[0]],
                            'slug' => get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() ),
                        ]]
                    ]]
                ];
            }

        }
    } else {
        $ret = "-1";
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

At the moment, it get all the posts of type event and order by `meta_key` "ovaem_date_start_time", but it should exclude all the past events.
What parameter should I pass to the `args` array to compare current meta_key value to today date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'ovaem_date_start_time',
                            'value' => time(),
                            'compare' => '>=',
                        )
                    )
```

Would something like this work, getting all events where the start date is greater than the current date, you may need to change the value as it depends what ovaem_date_start_time is actually saved as whether its time or datetime

Comment: Thanks You for the reply, tried your solution, but it still return the past events. PS: the meta_key "ovaem_date_start_time" is a timestamp

Comment: what type of field is ovaem_date_start_time saved as

Comment: Timestamp `"time": "1619827200",`

Comment: Maybe try the edited answer (i have not tested this)

Comment: Tried, still there.

Comment: looking at the full code canyou just change this line 
        if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ovaem_date_start_time')[0] < date("Y-m-d"))  and if ovaem_date_start_time is defo a time field as your stating change date("Y-m-d") to time()?

Comment: Looking at that row, I was got if var < date, but should be if var > time(), corrected and seems to work now